# Integration substitution: How do you find the derivative of the denominator?

Tags: integration, analysis, derivatives

I have to integrate:

$$
\int_1^2 \frac{37 x}{x^2-6 x+10} \, dx
$$

$$
=37 \int_1^2 \frac{x}{x^2-6 x+10} \, dx
$$

Then Wolfram Alpha tells me to rewrite the integrand as

$$
\frac{2 x-6}{2 \left(x^2-6 x+10\right)}+\frac{3}{x^2-6 x+10}
$$

I understand that for a proper substitution in the next step you would want to have the derivative of the denominator in the numerator.

But how does it know to add

$$
\frac{3}{x^2-6 x+10}
$$

on the right for example? And multiply the denominator by 2?

Of course, if you reverse simplify it it's clear but not like this.

Comment: Add the two rational functions together by getting a common denominator.  They are equal.  All WA did was subtract 6 and then add 6 and also separate into two integrals!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a usual trick when you need to compute $$I=\int \frac{a x}{bx^2+c x+d} \, dx$$ $$I=\frac ab \int \frac{b x}{bx^2+c x+d} \, dx=\frac {a}{2b} \int \frac{2b x}{bx^2+c x+d} \, dx=\frac {a}{2b} \int \frac{2b x+c-c}{bx^2+c x+d} \, dx$$So, finally $$I=\frac {a}{2b} \int \frac{2b x+c}{bx^2+c x+d} \, dx-\frac {ac}{2b} \int \frac{1}{bx^2+c x+d} \, dx$$ The first one is simple; for the second one, complete the square.

As you surely understand, we try to compose a numerator using the derivative of the denominator and then remove what had to be added.

Comment: Ah so you create the derivative of the denominator part by part and also remove all unnecessary parts which had to added for the equation still to work.

Comment: This is perfectly correct ! Simple, isn't it ? Remember the trick; it is extremely useful.

Comment: Thanks I'll write this formula down!

Comment: No, please ! Don't write the formula down. Just understand and reuse the trick.

Comment: Okay well I'll try that too.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{37x}{x^2-6x+10}=A\cdot\frac{\dfrac{d(x^2-6x+10)}{dx}}{x^2-6x+10}+\frac B{(x-3)^2+1^2}$$

$$\implies\frac{37x}{x^2-6x+10}=\frac{A(2x-6)}{x^2-6x+10}+\frac B{(x-3)^2+1^2}$$

Multiplying both sides by $x^2-6x+10,$

$$37x=2Ax+B-6A$$

Now compare the constants and the coefficients of $x$ to find $A,B$

Set $x^2-6x+10=u$ in the first integral and  $x-3=\tan\theta$ in the second

Answer (score 1):

This splitting is rigged exactly so that up to an overall constant, the first integral is $\int \frac{du}{u}$ after the "obvious" substitution $u = x^2 - 6 x + 10$.

You might find it more intuitive to complete the square first: Write the denominator as
$$x^2 - 6x + 10 = (x - 3)^2 + 1,$$ which suggests the substitution $v := x - 3$, $dv = dx$; applying this substitution transforms the integral to
$$37 \int_{-2}^1 \frac{v + 3}{v^2 + 1} dv.$$
Now we split in a much more transparent way, writing the integral as
$$\int_{-2}^1 \frac{v \,dv}{v^2 + 1} + 3\int_{-2}^1 \frac{dv}{v^2 + 1}.$$
The first integral can be evaluated with the substitution $w: = v^2 + 1$, $dw = 2v \,dv$, and the integrand of the second has antiderivative $\arctan v$.

If one undoes the substitution $v = x - 3$ in each of these integrals (and introduces a judicious factor of $\frac{1}{2}$) one recovers the integrands that WolframAlpha produces.